# "Number 12" meaning?

Tags: meaning, expressions

What is the meaning of "number 12" in the below sentence:

> You keep it up you're gonna put your number 12 down on a still some day an' git [sic] your head blowed [sic] off

EDIT: For more context, I've typed up the entire paragraph.

> "Understand you're quite a dancer," he informed me after waiting to see if I was going to continue. I wondered how much of his tomato face was due to weather and how much to alcohol. Around us the little bar-room conversations had died out. He wasn't satisfied to accept my silence. "I see you peart [sic] near ev'y [sic] day out thumpin' [sic] around that bresh [sic] out yonder," he said to me. **"You keep it up you're gonna put your number 12 down on a still some day an' git [sic] your head blowed [sic] off."**
>
> "I carry a spare."
>   He didn't get it for a minute. When he did he clouded over. "You in town for long Arnold?"

Arnold is a 'tree surgeon'. So now that I looked at it, it may just refer to one  of his tools (maybe an axe?). The author hadn't once mentioned a shotgun, although that does seem to make sense.

My original guess that that 'number 12' was a body part of sorts.

Comment: Possibly a 12 gauge shotgun, but hard to tell without context.

Comment: It's not a common idiom in the US.  An allusion to a 12-gauge shotgun is a good guess, as suggested by Cascabel.

Comment: Any chance it relates to tarot and numerology? I ask because shinin' and tarot are the two traditional vocations of widows and spinsters. Card 12 is the hanged man. Who spoke the line?

Comment: More context--e.g. where the sentence is from, and some information about the work that it's from--could add context that could help someone answer the question.

Comment: Cascabel’s is an excellent guess, but it is a wild shot (no pun intended) in the dark, which shouldn't have to be necessary. Please provide some more context than just a single sentence: what is the scene, who is speaking, what are they talking about in general, etc.

Comment: Aw shucks, I just perfected my answer and now you go and put it _on hold_...

Comment: The greater context from the extended quote suggests that the danger of getting his head blowed off comes not from the number 12 he carelessly puts down on the still, but from the owner of the still who thought it was sufficiently hidden in the bresh to avoid detection. It may even be that the number 12 is a reference to the narrator's shoe size; I don't know why an itinerant tree surgeon would be thumpin' around with a 12-gauge shotgun in the bresh on someone else's property, in any case.

Comment: Yep, shoe size. It follows from the dancing reference (which is a veiled threat), and from the fact that stills are hidden in caves or holes. Don't quite get the "tree surgeon" reference, unless the revenuer is using cruising as a pretense (this happens, and causes problems for actual cruisers). https://www.benmeadows.com/refinfo/techfacts/techpdf/timber_cruising_224.pdf

Comment: Shoe size sounds like a good guess to me too. The "blowed off" part may be referencing the use of the speaker's own gun.

Comment: I agree, after reading the extended text, that shoe size is just as likely. "I carry a spare." seems to indicate this, but it still is not clear. Just do not know why he did not say "size 12s", which is a much more common usage.

Answer (score 4):

Without any context I am going to take a "shot" at this...

I believe the speaker is referring to a [**#12 shotgun shell**](https://www.cheaperthandirt.com/product/ammo-12-gauge-rio-top-sporting-12-shot-2-3-4-1oz-load-box-of-25-rounds-amm-811.do), containing approximately 2400 pieces of soft shot. Usually used for killing snakes, it mostly has more bark than bite when fired from a 12 gauge shotgun at long range, and is ideal for scaring a prowler off without causing too much damage.

Phil Sweet has commented that the loose shell could have been kept handy for a purity test: evidently to test if the "run" is at 100 proof or higher, the powder from an opened casing could be mixed with the output and ignited: a bit of lore I was unaware of.

Clare has also commented that the #12 could refer to the [**Fox #12 shotgun**](http://www.chuckhawks.com/fox_BE_shotgun.htm), a high quality piece first produced in 1909, and thus relevant to the discussion.

***The umprovided context (I guess)***

Back in the day, clandestine liquor producers (moonshiners) would produce in a secluded spot in the woods during "season".

There were several points during production which were more dangerous, from a legal standpoint.

Approaching the site, it was possible there were "revenooers" waiting to arrest them. During the "run", if the wind changed or died off, it was still possible to be detected. Other dangers included thieves who would wait for the run to finish to steal it.

This is why most moonshiners kept a shotgun handy, to protect the still and "run".

Now the really dangerous part here is that it is generally a bad idea to mix firarms with alcohol. For most people producing "white lightning", there is always a temptation to taste the brew when it first is running. Apart from the fact the first "foreshots" are usually high in poisonous methanol, the ethanol produced at this point will be at its highest concentration:  if they are using a "thumper" it can go as high as 88%.

The better way to test purity is always with an alcoholometer, but seasoned pros use a "shake test" to estimate the purity.

IDIOTS taste-test. And if you taste too much and get blind drunk and stupid and lay your 12 gauge shotgun shell down on the hot still, there is a danger of "cooking off" a round--with disastrous results.

> You keep it up you're gonna put your number 12 down on a still some day an' git [sic] your head blowed [sic] off

So I figure that this is what an oldtimer was warning another (probably younger) partner about.

Comment: I will edit this later but right now I gotta go out and check the mash.

Comment: The shotgun itself seemed a better answer.

Comment: I also wondered if it was a warning against cooking off a shell. Another use for the shell is to provide the powder for a proof test. 100 proof meant that if you mixed black powder with the run, it would burn. This was more practical in the muzzle-loader days when you carried the powder in a horn.

Comment: @Clare Yeah, but the terminology does not work. Normally we would call it a "12 gauge", and the shells themselves are referred to by number going from "00" to #14, I think.

Comment: @PhilSweet That is a great observation, but do you mean 100% or 100 proof? 180 proof is pure alcohol (at least where I am from). 100 proof is more or less 55%, right about where I brew at, and I guarantee it will not catch fire from contact with powder.

Comment: It's ambiguous. "I have a Fox number 12 shotgun; no better gun was ever made."–Theodore Roosevelt, on what is perhaps  the most famous shotgun in American history. And to me, it's the gun which would more likely be referred to colloquially as "your number 12". People "forgetfully"  lay/lean/put/place their shotguns in all kinds of dangerous places.

Comment: @Clare GREAT CATCH! But I dont really know what to do with this post seeing as how it is _on hold_ (Grrr). I would like to edit your info and Phils in, but, oh well...I will follow up as I am enjoying myself with this piece.

Comment: @Cascabel No, you have to light it with a match, and the powder should do more than just sputter a bit. Less than 100 proof, and it won't burn. Btw, it seems powder is graded by numbered screens. Guess which number screen retains powder for a shotgun or big rifle. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pTzcd6D0cTA

Comment: @Clare "The [retail prices of Fox guns](http://www.chuckhawks.com/fox_BE_shotgun.htm) stayed the same from 1906 through 1912. An A grade gun was listed at $50, B grade at $75, C grade at $100, D grade at $200 and F grade at $500. Ejectors cost an extra $15, so the BE grade reviewed....retailed for $90 when it was made in 1909.
..cheap shotguns could be had at that time for about the price of Fox ejectors and a decent field grade double gun for around $25, and it becomes clear that Ansley Fox was marketing his guns based on their quality, rather than price." Still under consideration...

Comment: "[I] ran into the bedroom. I got the number 12 shotgun." ([Google](https://books.google.com/books?id=f10vAQAAIAAJ&q="Number+12+shotgun"&dq="Number+12+shotgun"&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjrj6mJjaXRAhVrslQKHbl9AD0Q6AEIJTAC)) Still  it doesn't match saying just 'the number 12'. But to me, in general, a shotgun blows one's head off, not the shells. But shells cooked from being placed on a still could also blow one's head off. But it's ambiguous and the whole thing is  still just a guess.

Comment: @Clare I edited in your comments and Phils--thanx so much. I guess without proper citation fronm the OP we will never know. Been fun!

Comment: @PhilSweet Great video, although his results were inconclusive for 50%. Loved the quote--"Alcohol, gunpowder and matches-what could go wrong?"  I think he was fair sozzled near the end...